# current_user nil value undefined in the view ruby on rails doorkeeper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper

**Updated with session data**

pastebin.com/nGGriw7e

---

I have a contests controller that inherits from application controller

We are using doorkeeper gem.

in the application controller we have the current_user defined and set as a helper method

```
helper_method :current_user, :require_user, :require_no_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= current_user_session && User.find(current_user_session.resource_owner_id)
  end

  private

  def current_user_session
    @current_user_session ||= Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_by_token session[:access_token]
  end
```

I am hitting url `/contests` which hits `contest#edit controller`

```
  def edit
    @contest = Contest.find params[:id]
  end
```

and inside this edit.html.erb I am rendering a side navigation partial first before rendering the edit stuff

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="left-nav">
    <% if @current_user.admin? or (@current_user.brand_admin? and @current_user == @contest.user) %>
      <% if @current_user.admin? %><li><%= link_to 'New Contest', new_contest_path %></li><% end %>
      <% if @contest and !@contest.new_record? %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Edit Contest', edit_contest_path(@contest) %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'All Contests', contests_path %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
</div
```

here is the server log

```
Started GET "/contests/5/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-18 17:29:14 -0400
Processing by ContestsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  Contest Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `contests`.* FROM `contests` WHERE `contests`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  Rendered contests/_side_nav.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered contests/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass:
```

in better errors I am getting the @current_user to be nil

```
>> @current_user
=> nil
```

which doesn't make sense. I am logged in and even set up this particular user to have a `role = "admin" inside rails c.`

Comment: And what do you have in session? Could you log it in controller action? (puts session.inspect)

Comment: here is what I have, I don't understand it. http://pastebin.com/nGGriw7e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take a look at session inspect, on the bottom of the log you can see

```
{"session_id"=>"a24e285e4a535cec4d7c20908aa40ef9", "_csrf_token"=>"oBOzksAaS2KkkfgOkA1q2Wj32UuSpFtoMZuW78Rse8U=", "current_user_id"=>42, "access_token"=>"635d45b8319c0b94f09d99fe463e4d4add3a1f40b179ea9720bbbf0f896fa252"}
```

It means that your application alread saves current_user_id, so I don't know if you should really search by access token.

Nevertheless, both should work fine.

Your problem is you use helper_method wrongly. Using this method means that rails "expose" this method to the view but by lazy evaluation. It means you should access it's instance variable by method name, not by instance_variable call. Try changing @current_user to current_user in the view. As you are memoizing it, it will make 1 call to database anyways.